Tikz figure includes "hidden" control points for bezier curves and makes my figure too big
I've drawn a diagram with some "wacky" curves using Bezier curves with the controls setting. It seems the size of the overall figure depends on these control points, even though they can't be seen. For example they can make the figure too wide so it's no longer centered and I get an Overfull \hbox warning. And they can create a large gap to the caption due to a control point below the curve.
Is there a way to tell latex to ignore these points for the purposes of displaying the figure?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% This is good
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-4,0) .. controls (0,1) .. (4,0);
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (8,2) and (-8,2) .. (4,0);
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (-4,2) .. (-2,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (-5,0) .. (0,1) .. controls (5,2) and (-4,0) .. (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

% This is no longer centered because the overall width of the figure spills over the page
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (0,1) .. (4,0);
        \draw (-4,0) .. controls (8,2) and (-8,2) .. (4,0);
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (-4,2) .. (-2,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (-5,0) .. (0,1) .. controls (5,2) and (-4,0) .. (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

% The gap to the caption is too large
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (0,1) .. (4,0);
        % \draw (-4,0) .. controls (8,2) and (-8,2) .. (4,0);
        \draw (-4,0) .. controls (-4,2) .. (-2,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (-5,0) .. (0,1) .. controls (5,2) and (-4,0) .. (4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


The bbox library comes from answer 501154.

You can use the bezier bounding box option from the bbox library to accurately calculate the bounding box:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-4,0) .. controls (-4,2) .. (-2,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (-5,0) .. (0,1) .. controls (5,2) and (-4,0) .. (4,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
        \draw (-4,0) .. controls (-4,2) .. (-2,-1) .. controls (0,-4) and (-5,0) .. (0,1) .. controls (5,2) and (-4,0) .. (4,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}



Perfect! Thankyou

@jonnybolton16 You're welcome!
